# dynamically add classes to content coming from *ngFor from an array

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

Im not quite sure something like this is possible but say in my html component I have an ngFor like so..

```
<div *ngFor="let card of cards">
   ... stuff in here
</div>
```

now say I have an array of classNames like so

```
classNames = [
   'red',
   'yellow',
   'blue',
   'green'
]
```

and inside my *ngFor I have a div like so

```
<div *ngFor="let card of cards">
   <div [class]='...'>
      <div class="card">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

basically what I want to happen is for every item in the ngFor give loop through the `classNames` array and dynamically add it to the incoming data so for example

say I have 6 items in cards so each card needs a classname so it loops through classNames and gives it a class so like this..

```
<div [class]='red'>
   <div class="card">
   </div>
</div>
<div [class]='yellow'>
   <div class="card">
   </div>
</div>
<div [class]='blue'>
   <div class="card">
   </div>
</div>
<div [class]='green'>
   <div class="card">
   </div>
</div>
<div [class]='red'>
   <div class="card">
   </div>
</div>
<div [class]='yellow'>
   <div class="card">
   </div>
</div>
```

and so on and so forth..

how could i accomplish something like this?

**EDIT**

component.html

```
<div class="card" *ngFor="let card of cards; let i = index">
   <div [class]="classNames[i%classNames.length]">
      ....
   </div> 
</div>
```

component.ts

```
export class...
  classNames = [
    'light-green',
    'dark-green',
    'aqua',
    'blue',
    'blue-purple',
    'purple',
    'purple-pink',
    'purple-orange'
  ];
```

Comment: you have to intilaize the array in .ts code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage [remainder (%)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) operator to achieve that:

```
<div *ngFor="let card of cards; let i = index">
   <div [class]="classNames[i%classNames.length]">
      <div class="card">
        {{ card }}
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/MPG8MXZGY4ZkKYENh6BU)**

**Update:**

You should define array as follows:

```
classNames = [
   'light-green',
   'dark-green',
   'aqua',
   'blue',
   'blue-purple',
   'purple',
   'purple-pink',
   'purple-orange'
];
```

**Note:** i use `=` instead of `:`

Comment: Hey Im getting this error `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Did you check my example? I think you're doing something wrong and don't see what i wrote

Comment: Ive done it exactly the same as your example, not sure why it wouldnt be working..

Comment: Can you reproduce it?

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of randomly applying any `class` to any `card` or deciding it on view based on some `%`, the best way, I believe would be read it from the `Cards` object itself, since it is logical to have all details of a `card` read from the `card` itself.

> So that view is independent of those extra stuffs.

```
classNames = ['red','yellow','blue','green'];
cards = [{text: 1, class: this.classNames[0]},{text: 2, class: this.classNames[1]}];
```

your view should simply do its task (render)

```
<div *ngFor="let card of cards; let i = index">
  <div [class]="card.class">
    <div class="card">
      {{ card.text}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The cards object comes from an api I have no control over, thus why Im doing it randomly, if I could put the classNames on the card itself I would

Comment: @JuvenileSnow that's where `view-model` come in picture